# More than 2 simultaneous connections to Win Server 2016

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Currently, on google compute engines, we can only have 2 simulatenous logins to a WinServer 2016 image. Is there any way we can have more? We'd be happy to buy more licences (through Google or Microsoft or some third party.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 simultaneous connections to the Windows Server is not a Google Cloud restriction, but a [Windows Server restriction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753380(v=ws.11).aspx).

To use more than 2, you will need to install RD Session host role service. This includes purchasing a [RD license](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21180.remote-desktop-licensing-demystified.aspx).